# Evitar Duplicidade no Cadastro PHP+MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

boa noite!

Como faço pra evitar que sejam realizado cadastros com as mesmas informações?

Atualmente meu "processa.php" está desta forma, e queria incluir a função citada acima...

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once ("conexao.php");

$nome = filter_input($INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input($INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$senha = filter_input($INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$cargo = filter_input($INPUT_POST, 'cargo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$setor = filter_input($INPUT_POST, 'setor', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha, cargo, setor, created) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$senha', '$cargo', '$setor', NOW())";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: cadastrar-usuario.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Usuário não foi cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: cadastrar-usuario.php");
}


?>
```

Comment: Acho que antes vc deveria definir o que seria único (nome, email), geralmente define-se o email como único, porque as outras informações podem variar. Aí vc verifica se o email já existe como condição para cadastrar ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Se quer uma coluna sendo única, utilize a ***unique constrain***. Apenas isso, somente isso.

```
create table pessoas (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    nome varchar(255),
    email varchar(255) unique
);
```

> Neste exemplo, a coluna `email` será única, enquanto a coluna `nome` pode se repetir.

Desta forma, sempre que fizer um `INSERT` de um e-mail que já existe, o banco de dados retornará um erro. Trate esse erro conforme a sua necessidade.

Fazer `SELECT` antes do `INSERT` para verificar se existe ou não o registro é gambiarra - sem contar que está sujeito a condições de corrida: o e-mail pode ser cadastrado entre as execuções do `SELECT` e do `INSERT`, ficando duplicado da mesma forma.